# Unable to change tab using self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, 3dtouch

My application is embedded within a `TabBarController`, I am trying to switch the selected tab from the `ViewController`.

With the following few lines I was hoping to find out if the function worked, unfortunately it does not but I am unsure why, can anybody help out where I am going wrong ?

```
func tabbar() { self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4 }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabbar()

}
```

PS: The reason I am testing this is because I wanted to find out if the following will work for my `3DTouchShortcuts`. I know the 3D Touch Shortcuts appear and open the initial view controller, I am hoping the following line for each case would actually make the shortcut open to different tabs.

> tababarController.selectedIndex = 1

```
private func handleShortcutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) {

     if let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController, let shortcutItemType = ShortcutItemType(shortcutItem: shortcutItem) {
        let tabbarController = rootViewController as! UITabBarController

        switch shortcutItemType {
        case .AddItem:
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("performsegueAddItem", object: nil)
            tabbarController.selectedIndex = 1
            break
        case .FavouritesTab:
            tabbarController.selectedIndex = 2
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try moving it to viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: You have so many different spelling for your `tababarController` `tabbarController` `tabBarController` and so on. I would't be surprised it doesn't work

Comment: @LeoDabus I corrected the misspelling, check again

Comment: try `tabBarController`

Comment: @LeoDabus instead of `self.tabBarController` within my `tabbar` function ? If so I have tried and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: use `tabBarController` everywhere and try calling `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 4` inside viewDidLayoutSubviews instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: @LeoDabus alright it seems without using `.self` and calling it inside viewDidLayoutSubviews worked. Using viewdidload actually crashed because optional value is nil. Thank you (Y) PS: Does the `handleShortcutItem` seem fine to you  ?

Comment: @LeoDabus If you put your suggestions as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to call it inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad` and you should use `tabBarController` when calling it. You should also use `guard` to unwrap it:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    guard let tabBarController = tabBarController else { return }
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

more easy

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self .selectedIndex = 2 // desired index
}
```