# How do I center a UIActivityIndicatorView programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to place my activity indicator in the centre of my table view controller programmatically but when I run my code it always appears in the top left hand corner.

Here is my swift code;

```
let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.style = .large
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.color = .white
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    return activityIndicator
}()

tableView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.centerXAnchor),
    activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.centerYAnchor)
])
    
tableView.layoutSubviews()
```

[image: activity indicator]

Comment: try to execute your code inside viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: @LeoDabus You can't implement any code inside that method.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can always override that method in your view controller, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35097218/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus ah I see what you mean. I’ll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

```
  lazy var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.style = .large
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.color = .white
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    return activityIndicator
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include the line;

```
activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: Isn't that what the answer by Dinesh suggested ? If that is what helped you, you should probably accept his answer.